# LZW compression differences between Global Mapper and gdal_translate

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I compressed an GeoTIFF image with both gdal_translate and Global Mapper with LZW compression. The one Global Mapper compressed is much smaller, is almost 30% of the one gdal_translate compressed.

`gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -co PREDICTOR=2 1.tif lzw1.tif`

How can I compress it further like Global Mapper?

Answer (score 2):

I figure out finally. 
Global Mapper did:
1. LZW compression
2. RGB to 256 palette
the tiff files are almost 10 times smaller size than before.

I use:
gdal_translate:
1. with LZW compression
2. quality compress 40% but still RGB
gdaladdo
make 6 levels of overview.

Comment: I also use gawk and shell to read the paths of the original tiff files and generate a new shell script to do the above work automatically. The scripts are running well on Ubuntu.